# Bash script to read a password once and use it for many files

Tags: bash

I'm writing a Bash script to encrypt a lot of files using `zip -e`, and right now I have to use `zip -P "plaintextpassword"` to get it to work. **I'd like to have my script prompt securely for a password once, then use the same one for a bunch of files.** My script looks something like

`for f in *; do zip -v -P "plaintextpassword" "$f.zip" "$f"`

This results in a whole lot of separate .zip files, which is what I want.

Comment: And which part are you having trouble with? What did you search for and what did you find? How did you try to apply that and how did it fail?

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that on a multi-user system, everybody who can display the process list, can see the password.

Comment: Interesting read: http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Bash-Tips-Passing-Passwords

Comment: U. Windl, I've heard that, that's exactly what I was thinking to avoid. I should be the only person using my system, but if I can do it without the password right there in htop, then that would be better.

Comment: kvantour, thanks for that article! So that gives me an idea; could I just do `echo "plaintextpassword" > pass.txt` and then `sudo chmod 600 pass.txt` and read the password from that file? Then only I should be able to read it, right? And as long as I'm the user running the script, the script will still work.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you'd use something like this to read the password:

```
IFS= read -sr -p "Enter a password: " password
echo
```

The `IFS=` prefix keeps `read` from trimming spaces and tabs, the `-r` keeps it from trying to parse backslashes as escapes, `-p "Enter a password: "` supplies the prompt, `-s` keeps it from echoing as you type, and then `echo` at then end goes to the next line (normally handled by echoing the carriage return at the end of input... but `-s` suppresses that).

Then use the password like this:

```
for f in *; do zip -v -P "$password" "$f.zip" "$f"
```

Note that this isn't all that secure, because the arguments passed to commands (including the password argument to `zip`) are basically public info, easily viewable with the `ps` command.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without passing the password in a publicly viewable way? Could I maybe store the password in a file and delete it after the script reads it?

Comment: @Geometer Storing passwords in files has its own problems (the data tends to persist even after you "delete" the file, although it's hard to access). But in this case it's irrelevant because `zip` doesn't seem to have an option to read the password from a file. It can read from stderr, but only if that's a tty (not a plain file), so you'd have to create a pseudo-tty and feed the password to that..... ick. Basically, `zip` doesn't have very good options for supplying the password, and you're stuck with what it provides.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the password and store as a `variable` and pass to the `for` loop in bash shell

```
#!/bin/bash
# Read Password
echo -n Password:
read -s password

for f in *;
do
        zip -v -P "$password" "$f.zip" "$f"
done
```

Comment: As the question is tagged `bash`, you probably also want to use the `-s` option to disable echoing the user's input to the screen. In any case, use `IFS= read -r password` to ensure that what the user types is preserved literally.

Answer (score 1):

While not really an answer, it is always nice to quote the man-page:

> **`-P password`**
>          **`--password password`**
>                 Use  password  to encrypt zipfile entries (if any).  THIS IS INSECURE!  Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other user; even on stand-alone systems there is
>                 always the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking.  Storing the plaintext password as part of a command line in an automated script is even worse.  Whenever possible, use the non-echoing, interactive prompt to enter  pass‐
>                 words.  (And where security is truly important, use strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively weak standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.)
>
> **<sub>source: `man zip`</sub>**